# Error while binding a ListBox, Items' values are nulls!

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, data-binding, listbox

I have a List of Customers.

Customer is an object generated by Linq To SQL Data Context.

I also have a ListBox as well. I have set the DisplayMember to "name" and the ValueMember to "id".

but while I'm trying to do the following:

```
    private void FillList(List<Customer> list)
    {
        lstCustomers.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Customer c in list) // list here is the List<Customer> object
        {
            lstCustomers.Items.Add(c);
        }
    }
```

The list item is displayed correctly (the name of the customer), but the Value of the list items (IDs) are nulls!

My question is why they are nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

((Customer)lstCustomers.SelectedItem).id

Comment: No, this is not my issue. what happens is the SelectedValue is null

Comment: If i understand you correctly after you select the SelectedValue it returns null. If that's the case check it the Properties of the Customer is same id and not ID or Id. or if the list return you id values.

Comment: You also use ((Customer)lstCustomers.SelectedItem).id see if it works.

Comment: How could I flag a comment as an answer :o ?

Comment: You set it as answered in my answer! :P

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to set the data source of the listbox for that to work.

```
lstCustomers.DataSource = list;
```

You're probably just seeing the `ToString()` of the Customer objects displayed in the listbox.

Comment: The problem is that I DO NOT want to set the DataSource, cuz that prevent me from dealing with items in the ListBox unless it DOES NOT have a DataSource, that what i've figured!

Comment: I agree with @orn here.  Maybe you can explain in your question why setting `listCustomers.DataSource` doesn't work for you?  You can generally "deal with" the items in the ListBox even with the `DataSource` property set.

Comment: @ckittel, if, for example, tried to remove an item from the ListBox while the datasource is set, I get a runtime error says that i can't change items when the datasource is set!

Comment: @Hashem remove the item from the datasource instead.  That's the point of the datasource, the combobox is just a "view" that sits on top of the datasource.  Adding, removing, mutating the items should all happen in the datasource.

Comment: @ckittel, hmmm that's right, I'm sorry, my view about data binding is poor, but your notice is great for me. Adding and removing are DataSource jobs. Thanks ckittel :)